# How to convert seconds from Epoch time to UTC time in Pyspark?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe with a column name epoch that is seconds from epoch time and I wanted to convert it to UTC time. How to do it in Pyspark?

I dont want to harcode "GMT-7" and I want to make sure I use the right offset for the time, GMT-7 or GMT-8 based on daylight savings. I'm running Spark 2.1

```
myDF = myDF.withColumn("epoch_tmst",(myDF.epoch.cast(dataType=TimestampType()))
myDF = myDF.withColumn("epoch_tmst_utc",to_utc_timestamp(myDF.epoch_tmst,"GMT-7"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please provide a sample of your data and expected output? It'd be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert unixtime into UTC timestamp directly by pyspark method.
(You can do unix->GMT-7 & GMT-7->UTC separately by pyspark, but looks like that's not what you want)

How about take them into literal string once, and use Python's time module?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime